# Proving the existence of a Symmetric Bayesian equilibrium

Tags: game-theory, bayesian, nash-equilibrium

I am currently faced with the following question:

Consider the public goods game. Suppose that there are $I > 2$ players and that
the public goods is supplied (with benefit of 1 for all players) only if at least $K$ players
contribute. The players' costs of contribution $\theta_1,...,\theta_I$ are private information, and
independently and uniformly distributed on $[0.5, 1.5]$.

Let $K=1$. Prove that there is a symmetric Bayesian Nash equilibrium, where
each player contributes if his cost is less than or equal to $c^*$ (same for all players) and
0.5 < $c^*$ < 1.

I was thinking to use the 'First Price Auction' method to find the symmetric and linear equilibrium for this question. However, I am not sure how to proceed. I would appreciate your kind help! Thank you!

Update:

Player $i$ contributes iff $\theta_i \leq c^*$, then the expected payoff to player $i$ = ($1-\theta_i$)

If $\theta_i \geq c^*$, then the payoff to player $i$ is $1$ (if at least 1 other player contributes), $0$ (no one else contributes)

Expected payoff to player $i$ = $1$ x P(at least one other player contributes) = 1 $-$ P(no one else contributes) = $1 - (1.5 - c^*)^{I-1}$

Hence, player $i$ should contribute iff ($1-\theta_i$) $>$ $1 - (1.5 - c^*)^{I-1}$ and then we solve for $c^*$

Comment: It looks kind of ok (some details are missing). In order to proceed: from your last inequality, what is the threshold below which player $i$ contributes? Find that, set it equal to $c^*$ and then solve. Even if you cannot solve it in closed form you are only asked to show that $c^*\in(0.5,1)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "use the first price auction method."
Here's a suggestion on how to proceed: Assume that all $I-1$ opponents of player $i$ use the same cutoff strategy $c$. Show that player $i$'s (Bayesian) best response is also a cutoff strategy and calculate the cutoff (call it, e.g.,  $c_i$). This should be a function of $c$. Then, to establish a symmetric BNE, assume $c_i=c=c^*$ and solve for $c^*$.

Comment: Thank you @pegasus! Will give it a try. Cheers!

Comment: Feel free to accept my answer if it works!

Comment: Hi @pegasus! Sorry, I am still struggling to even start despite your suggestions! I hope I am able to ask for more guidance!

Comment: Pne more hint: You will need to calculate the probability that at least one player other than $i$ contributes. This should be equal to the probability that at least one player other than $i$ has a cost below $c$. Given this, when is it a best response for player $i$ to contribute?

Comment: Hi @pegasus! Sorry, I was away. I have the following! Not too sure if I am right - the probability of at least one player other than $i$ contributing = $c^* - 0.5$. If this happens, then the best response of player $i$ is to not contribute since only one player is required to contribute for everyone to benefit

Comment: Under the situation when $1.5 - c^*$, then it will be a best response for player $i$ to contribute

Comment: @Mathuser, how did you calculate the probability? From player $i$'s point of view some other player $j$ contributes iff $\theta_j<c$. So, she has probability to contribute $p_j=\mathop{Pr}(\theta_j<c)=F(c)=c-0.5$. But this is only one opponent. What is the probability that *at least one* of her $I-1$ opponents to contribute?

Comment: @Mathuser Also, even after having calculated this probability, there will always be some chance that no one else contributes. Isn't it better, then for player $i$ to contribute? In order to calculate player $i$'s best response, you should write down her expected utility and see for which value of $\theta_i$ she is better off contributing.

Comment: Hi @pegasus! I understand what you have said! I have updated my original post with some workings. Not too sure if I am doing the right stuff!